# How to format a timestamp from DynamoDB for Elasticsearch/Kibana?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, kibana

I'm pushing **DynamoDB** rows into a **Elasticsearch** cluster. The date fields are **unix timestamps** and not recognized by **Kibana** as a date.

I read about [Elasticsearch mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/mapping.html#all-mapping-types) and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716435/elasticsearch-index-unix-timestamp), but don't know where to implement the mapping in my **Lambda** script:

```
/* ... requires and config ... */

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {        
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        var dbRecord = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb);
        postToES(dbRecord, context, callback);
    });
};

function postToES(doc, context, lambdaCallback) {
    var req = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint);

    req.method = 'POST';
    req.path = path.join('/', esDomain.index, esDomain.doctype);
    req.region = esDomain.region;
    req.headers['presigned-expires'] = false;
    req.headers['Host'] = endpoint.host;
    req.body = doc; 

    // Maybe here?

    var signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req , 'es');  
    signer.addAuthorization(creds, new Date());

    var send = new AWS.NodeHttpClient();
    send.handleRequest(req, null, function(httpResp) {
        var respBody = '';
        httpResp.on('data', function (chunk) {
            respBody += chunk;
        });
        httpResp.on('end', function (chunk) {
            lambdaCallback(null,'Lambda added document ' + doc);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        lambdaCallback('Lambda failed with error ' + err);
    });
}
```

**Elasticsearch document**

```
{
    _index: "posts",
    _type: "post",
    _id: "6YKF2AAV06RSSRrzv6R-",
    _version: 1,
    found: true,
    _source: {
        ApproximateCreationDateTime: 1499922960,
        Keys: {
            id: {
                S: "7asda8b0-628a-11e7-9e5e-25xyc7179dx7"
            }
        },
        NewImage: {
            posted_at: {
                N: "1499922995401"
            },
            id: {
                S: "7asda8b0-628a-11e7-9e5e-25xyc7179dx7"
            }
        },
        SequenceNumber: "2442423900000000003279639454",
        SizeBytes: 221,
        StreamViewType: "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
    }
}
```

**Dynamoose Schema**

```
var Schema = dynamoose.Schema;
var s = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        hashKey: true,
        required: true
    },
    posted_at: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = dynamoose.model('posts', s);
```

Example: in my DynamoDB table I've the field `posted_at`. The content is a unix timestamp. In Kiabana it's indexed as

- `NewImage.posted_at.N` *(type: string, searchable, analyzed)* and
- `NewImage.posted_at.N.keyword` *(type: string, searchable, aggregateable)*

I'm confused by the `N` and `type: string`.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the mapping that's been created for you by ES?

Comment: @Val The field name in the DynamoDB table is `posted_at`. In Kibana it's indexed as `NewImage.posted_at.N` (type: string, searchable, analyzed) and `NewImage.posted_at.N.keyword` (type: string, searchable, aggregateable).

Comment: Thanks. Can you show a sample document as well?

Comment: @Val Copied from the DynamoDB: `{ "posted_at": 1498794511820 }`

Comment: No I'd need a document that's been indexed into ES, not one from DynamoDB

Comment: @Val please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149094/discussion-between-mr-b-and-val).

Comment: Any idea why `{ "posted_at": 1498794511820 }` gets transformed into `{ "posted_at": {"N": "1498794511820"} }` ?

Comment: @Val No, unfortunately not. I'm using `Dynamoose` for my models and `posted_at` has the type `Date`. The field in the table has the type `Number`. Interesting: every `Number` was transformed into `string`, except `SizeBytes`, which was probably created by Elasticsearch itself (it's not in my DB).

Comment: Do you mind to share your Dynamoose code?

Comment: @Val please have a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it turns out that the `N` is there to denote the [DynamoDB attribute type](https://dynamoosejs.com/api#attribute-types) (i.e. `N` stands for `Number`).

The problem is that the number gets stringified and thus indexed as a string in ES (i.e. what you currently see in your mapping).

We can get around this using a dynamic template definition. First delete your index in ES and the corresponding index pattern in Kibana. Then run this command:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/post_template -d '{
  "template": "posts",
  "mappings": {
    "post": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "dates": {
            "path_match": "NewImage.posted_at.N",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type":  "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Finally you can reindex your data through Dynamoose and you should be able to find a date field in Kibana afterwards.

Comment: Oh lord, `stringify()`, of course! Thank you! What kind of template is it and where should I run it? :)

Comment: You need to install this template in your ES server. I've updated the command to use curl instead.